# defend dos attack

Tags: dos

my website is crippled due to simple request from many ranges of ips, tens of thousands or more request per second.  
Is there a way to defend this kind of attack?   
Is there a way to trace back to the attacker?

Comment: Sadly there's nothing much you can do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

```
apt-get install mod-dosevasive
```

But this question belongs on serverfault.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how is this module supposed to work? (the information on the internet is somewhat sparse and the project seems to be dead, website unreachable). In my understanding it does some kind of "evasion" (rate limiting? blocking? whatever?) inside apache. How does that help against dozens of hosts from many IP subnets physically saturating your line, and server processes being busy sorting out those ten thousand requests per second? The only effective ways to stop a DDOS that I know is taking the server offline or blocking 50% of the internet high up the router hierarchy.

Comment: It means it does not serve request from a certain IP anymore for a certain amount of time, if there are too many requests from the same IP in a certain amount of time. Thus not slowing the server down by starting too many processes, and second not sending an answer back, thus not saturating the line. However, the mod is called DOS-evasive, not DDOS-evasive. You can also block the IPs with iptables (firewall), has the same effect, and the effectiveness may be even better.