# how to stop anybody from abusing my contact page

Tags: javascript, security, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a website and contact page in it. Anybody can go in there and write something to contact us and it will be sent to my email address. Today i noticed almost 100 emails in my inbox and somebody has tried to send junk using some javascript. How do i stop this?  One way i thought of is to put a captcha. But is there a better way to stop right at the client side itself rather than checking on a server?

Comment: Bu how do i determine if it is legitimate client or not? Human client or a automated client?

Comment: Filter all inputs anyway, htmlentities is your best friend :P

Comment: To stop anybody, take it offline. If anybody can use it at that point, you got problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy technique to implement is to place a honeypot input like `<input type="text" name="email2" />` and hide it by css `input[name="email2"] { display: none; }`. All you have to do on serverside is to check if bots have set this field to some value. If they did so they're bots.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, have you practically used it somewhere ?

Comment: GravityForms provides such kind of challenging.

Comment: You mean to say like i can set it to some value say XYZ and bots will set it to something else and then i can compare in the server side? If so all that the bot creator has to do is check my page source and see what i am setting to. So i am kinda not clear on where this solution is going

Comment: The technique is effective against lazy drive-by bots, but not targeted attacks (it is also a server side technique).

Answer (score 6):

> But is there a better way to stop right at the client side itself rather than checking on a server?

No — the client is under the control of the user, so anything you do there can be bypassed.

Any anti-spam measures (rate limiting, bayesian filtering, CAPTCHAs, etc) must be checked on the server.

Comment: So if i have to check in the server side, still the spammer is harming my website by making my webserver busy with his requests. Is there a way to stop this?

Comment: [Defending against DOS attacks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6979098/defend-dos-attack) is more of a systems question than a programming question and has been marked as off-topic previously.

Answer (score 0):

Long story short:  If you dont want scripts or bots trolling you, put up something such as a captcha.... Or you could limit the ip to sending 1 submission per ip or on a timer countdown before another resend is allowed.

Comment: sidenote:  You can spoof IPs if you are a real hacker/a-hole, but most stupid ermm.... less intelligent... kids would be stopped in their tracks.